# How to use Java classes in stjs project?

Tags: java

I have developed a core Java project. Now I need to change core Java code into jQuery format for a phonegap application. This code conversion is because I am using stjs project, which does not run java code - for example `System`, `HashMap`, `ArrayList` et cetera. It only allows variable and setter and getter methods created js file.

Could you please suggest me if I am going a correct path or not? I am getting the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.stjs.generator.MultipleFileGenerationException: 
The usage of the class java.lang.System is not allowed. 
If it's one of your own bridge types, please add the annotation 
@STJSBridge to the class or to its package.(Mytest.java:19)
```

Comment: Why are you using Java then? Throw it all out and work on Javascript.

Comment: Thanks,Actually my java project contains lot of classes and and jar files,Now i can change manually each and every class its take lot of time right,I need any code convertion tool for java to JQuery,Any code convertion tool are available not? How can I do it? Please give me any suggestions about it and suggestions about tools that can help me with this.

Comment: Search the __web__. Take a __[tour]__.